# resize ubuntu space in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I use mac air and
I want to resize my ubuntu space to 30G in virtualbox

But the path has `space` in `VirtualBox VMs`

so when I run

```
VBoxManage modifyhd /Users/winsome/VirtualBox VMs/Helloserver/Helloserver.vdi --resize 30720
```

it said : 
    Syntax error: Invalid parameter 'VMs/Helloserver.vdi'

After try the method @fablife teach me.it works:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "/Users/winsome/VirtualBox VMs/Helloserver/Helloserver.vdi" --resize 30720
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

But when I ssh to my ubuntu to ckeck `df`
The space didn't extend (/dev/sda1        7608792 5024384 2174860   70% /)
how can I do next??

```
檔案系統       1K-blocks    已用    可用 已用% 掛載點
/dev/sda1        7608792 5024384 2174860   70% /
none                   4       0       4    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev              240120       4  240116    1% /dev
tmpfs              50180     884   49296    2% /run
none                5120       0    5120    0% /run/lock
none              250892     152  250740    1% /run/shm
none              102400      48  102352    1% /run/user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "/Users/winsome/VirtualBox VMs/Helloserver.vdi" --resize 30720
```

putting the path in parenthesis?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another questtion so I edit the question.hope you don't mind

Comment: I am sorry, I was able to answer your first question because it's related to how to use a linux shell. The second question is related to virtualbox. I suggest you create a new question with only the second part.

Comment: ok,thanks a lot for heliping